# How can I resolve the NaN values generated by cv2.cvtcolor when trying to work with a FITS file?

Tags: python, opencv, astropy, fits

I am using the CASTLES dataset of strong lensing events and attempting to classify images of galaxies as lensing events or not.

When I check for any NaN values in the FITS image itself, I cannot find any:

```py
    img_g = fits.open(os.path.join(path, os.listdir(path)[0]))
    img = img_g[0].data

    print(np.any(np.isnan(img))) --> (False)
```

But when I attempt to format the image into the proper number of color channels, I get the following:

```
  pic = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    for i in pic[0]:
      if np.any(np.isnan(i)):
        print(i) --> [nan, nan, nan]
```

In addition, NaN values pop up when I am trying to resize the image:

```
    pic = cv2.resize(img,(256,256))
    print(np.any(np.isnan(pic))) --> (True)
```

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong or if there is any way to remove these NaN values while preserving the image? I will provide more information if necessary.

Comment: Are you sure the incoming image is BGR?

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm unsure, but if the image is not BGR, what would I use to format the color channels? OpenCV cvtcolor does not seem to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There ARE no color channels.  Those are grayscale images.  I downloaded the set to check.  All 137 images are grayscale.  If you're going to false color them, it's up to you to do the transformation.

### Followup

You can't just convert these images to color.  It doesn't make sense.  I looked at one sample file, and the values ranged from -0.0289 to +0.224.  If I give you a value of 0.18, what color is that?  If I give you -0.02, what color is that?

Here's a way to visualize these files, using a 2D plot:

```
from astropy.io import fits
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = fits.open('q256.fits')
img = f[0].data

plt.imshow(img,interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

If I `cd Castles/B2319/FIT/NIC2H` and run that script, I get this:
[image]

but that is an artifact of matplotlib applying a colormap.  If that's what you want, YOU have to do the color mapping.  OpenCV cannot do that.

Comment: The issue is that even when I use a grayscale transformation such as cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB or attempt to resize the image using OpenCV, I still get NaN values. Would you have any ideas as to why this is?

Comment: It's an unusual format, because it's 32-bit grayscale.  You probably have to tell OpenCV about that.  I'll try a couple.